# Functional derivative acts on covariant derivative

Tags: general-relativity, hamiltonian-formalism, poisson-brackets, functional-derivatives, adm-formalism

I'm confusing about how functional derivatives act on a covariant derivative. I'm doing such a calculation:
In ADM formalism, let $h_{ij}(x)$ be the spatial metric while $\pi^{ij}(x)$ is its momentum conjugate. Then, am I correct to write done, for $m^k(x)$
the test function that is independent on $h_{ij}$ and $\pi^{ij}$,
$$\begin{split}
&\frac{\delta}{\delta \pi^{rs}(z)}\left[h_{jk}(x)\nabla_i\pi^{ij}(x)m^k(x)\right]\\
=&h_{jk}(x)m^k(x)\frac{\delta}{\delta \pi^{rs}(z)}\left[\partial_i\pi^{ij}(x)+\bar{\Gamma}^i_{il}\pi^{jl}(x)+\bar{\Gamma}^i_{jl}\pi^{il}(x)\right]\\
=&h_{jk}m^k\left[\delta^{ij}_{rs}\partial_i+\bar{\Gamma}^i_{il}\delta^{jl}_{rs}+\bar{\Gamma}^i_{jl}\delta^{il}_{rs}\right]\delta^{(3)}(x-z)\\
=&h_{jk}m^k\left[\delta^{ij}_{rs}\nabla_i+\bar{\Gamma}^i_{il}\delta^{jl}_{rs}+\bar{\Gamma}^i_{jl}\delta^{il}_{rs}\right]\delta^{(3)}(x-z)
\end{split}$$
where in the third line I consider that functional derivative commutes with odinary spatial derivative and in the last step I think ordinary derivative works the same as covariant derivative when acting on delta function?

Comment: Is this from a reference? Which page?